# How can I display trash bin of root?

Tags: trash

I had trash bin for root: `/.Trash/0/` But there is no way to display that trash bin. I try to open nautilus in root privilege. But the trash bin is still empty.

In ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Did you enable root for login?  Check the contents of `~/.local/share/Trash` and `/root/.local/share/Trash`

Comment: no I do not want to enable root for login! So there actually no way to handle this, if the root home does not exist?

Comment: Just suggestions on where to look.  Running GUI programs with root privileges is generally not recommended, as situations like this do arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally GUI program cannot see root privilege files and one should not run GUI with root. Also there is not trash bin for root unless we use something like trash-cli and had run it with sudo.

The /.Trash in other hand is actually created by mount the root partition in other OS such as live-CD. It won't be accessible by current OS. The way to access it is to use gvfs